# How to make a colormap of data in matplotlib (Python)?

Tags: matplotlib, color-mapping

Hear a clip of my very long data file:

```
330.0000, 340.0000, 2.336e-9
340.0000, 340.0000, 2.346e-9
350.0000, 340.0000, 2.303e-9
360.0000, 340.0000, 2.329e-9
340.0000, 340.0000, 2.338e-9
380.0000, 340.0000, 2.335e-9
390.0000, 340.0000, 2.343e-9
```

How to make a colormap out of it? It should look like this:

[image: Colormap]

Here is what I tried so far [based on the manual](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nrows = max(len(cmap_list) for cmap_category, cmap_list in cmaps)
gradient =  []
with open('inputfile.txt') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        results.append(line.strip().split(','))
gradient = np.vstack((gradient, gradient))


def plot_color_gradients(cmap_category, cmap_list):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows)
    fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.95, bottom=0.01, left=0.2, right=0.99)
    axes[0].set_title(cmap_category + ' colormaps', fontsize=14)

    for ax, name in zip(axes, cmap_list):
        ax.imshow(gradient, aspect='auto', cmap=plt.get_cmap(name))
        pos = list(ax.get_position().bounds)
        x_text = pos[0] - 0.01
        y_text = pos[1] + pos[3]/2.
        fig.text(x_text, y_text, name, va='center', ha='right', fontsize=10)

    # Turn off *all* ticks & spines, not just the ones with colormaps.
    for ax in axes:
        ax.set_axis_off()

for cmap_category, cmap_list in cmaps:
    plot_color_gradients(cmap_category, cmap_list)

plt.show()
```

Hopefully you can help me.

Comment: 1. I edited the markup of your code. Please make sure that I did so correctly, that part after `with open(...` was a bit ambiguous. Please edit if necessary. 2. I'm not sure I understand. How should the 3 columns in your data be interpreted in terms of a colormap? 3. What you've tried so far: does it work? Does it not? How's so? Currently you don't have a question in your question.

Comment: Your main hurdle here is the need to pivot your data into an N-by-M array. where N and M are the number of distinct values in the first and second columns, respectively